# Rhythmbox is not launching

Tags: 13.10, rhythmbox, segmentation-fault

I'm using  Rhythmbox 2.99 in Ubuntu 13.10, and when I first launch the application it searches for music and works like a charm, but if I try to launch it later again nothing happens. When I run it in terminal I get this:

```
$ rhythmbox
(rhythmbox:8860): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: Custom constructor for class SoupServer returned NULL (which is invalid).  Unable to remove object from construction_objects list, so memory was probably just leaked.  Please use GInitable instead. 

Segmentation fault
```

Any ideas how to make it work again?

The output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep rhythmbox`:

```
ii  gir1.2-rb-3.0                          2.99.1-0ubuntu1                         amd64        GObject introspection data for the rhythmbox music player
ii  librhythmbox-core7                     2.99.1-0ubuntu1                         amd64        support library for the rhythmbox music player
ii  rhythmbox                              2.99.1-0ubuntu1                         amd64   music player and organizer for GNOME
ii  rhythmbox-data                         2.99.1-0ubuntu1                         all           data files for rhythmbox
ii  rhythmbox-mozilla                      2.99.1-0ubuntu1                         amd64         Rhythmbox Mozilla plugin
ii  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder            2.99.1-0ubuntu1                         amd64        burning plugin for rhythmbox music player
ii  rhythmbox-plugin-equalizer             0.3-2                                   all          rhythmbox sound equalizer
ii  rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist             2.99.1-0ubuntu1                         all          zeitgeist plugin for rhythmbox music player
ii  rhythmbox-plugins                      2.99.1-0ubuntu1                         amd64        plugins for rhythmbox music player
```

Comment: Did you close the `rhythmbox` properly before launching it again? I mean when you start `rhythmbox` and when you normally close it using alt+F4 or from the window it doesn't close properly. You can close rhythmbox properly by typing this command in terminal `pkill rhythmbox`. Then try to re-launch again. Reply..

Comment: That's not the case, because I can't lauch it even after a system restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try these once**

1. First try to re-configure it, if it doesn't help then follow the step 2.

   ```
   sudo pkill rhythmbox
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure rhythmbox
   ```

   Check after Log-out/ Restart.
2. If first doesn't help then re-install rhythmbox after removing all configuration file:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove rhythmbox
   sudo apt-get --purge remove rhythmbox
   sudo find / | grep rhythmbox | sudo xargs rm -rf
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install rhythmbox
   ```

   Check after Log-out/Restart.

Reply if you get any error at any particular command.

Comment: The first one didn't help, the second one gave a new error in terminal, and the app still doesn't launch, sorry for the bad editing:

~$ rhythmbox
rhythmbox: error while loading shared libraries: librhythmbox-
core.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or 
directory

Comment: It seems that `rhythmbox` doesn't install properly, one library file is missing.. You can install it by: `sudo apt-get -f install librhythmbox*`. If still it gives your error then post the output of this command in your question(not in comment): `sudo dpkg -l | grep rhythmbox`

Comment: I somehow managed to solve the problem by uninstall, and reinstall completely all the packages that are related to rhythmbox. It works now, but the GUI is english and my system is hungarian, is there a way to change it?

Comment: First good to know that you managed to install it. I think you've to install plugins for rhythmbox that you've to search in google or in `Synaptic`

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the db file .local/share/rhythmbox/rhythmdb.xml . It's probably corrupted and keeping Rhythmbox from starting.
It will be recreated automatically, you will only lose some data like song ratings (data not included in file metadata, mainly). You will not lose your playlists.
Give Rhythmbox a few seconds to start scenning music folders and repopulate the database.

Comment: it did not have any effect on 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04. if i start the player in terminal with the command `rhythmbox`, i get the error `(rhythmbox:31511): Rhythmbox-CRITICAL **: Timeout was reached
` after around 10 secs.

Comment: it started after i did `pkill rhythmbox`. the db also looks good now, which was really messed up earlier with songs skipping randomly. thanks